# Differences between presentViewController and performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

This is a kinda conceptual question (not trying to solve a particular problem but to understand things better) that I encountered.

`IBOutlets` in view controllers are "forcedly unwrapped" variables by default and I don't know exactly why but it tells me that iOS expects each one of them to be initialized when the VC is called.

I have a view controller `A` and two other ones `B` and `C`. I have a click listener to a custom button of mine in `A` that depending a certain variable, decides after the click if `B` or `C` are going to be called.

I tried implementing this with `presentViewController` but for some reason my program crashed in runtime because of non-initialized outlets in either `B` or `C`.

However, I named by segues and tried the same thing with `performSegueWithIdentifier` and it just worked.

I wanna know, what are all the differences between them and is everything I told I know correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How were you allocating your view controllers? If you made them in the storyboard you need to allocate them with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.  If you just `alloc` `init` them it won't load the view you created in the storyboard.

Comment: interesting. They were created in the Storyboard but had custom classes. I just thought I could invoke them passing their classes.

Comment: Going with dan's comment: In Swift-speak, you need to make sure you do an `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` with an identifier you assigned to the view controller that you want to instantiate in the storyboard. You cannot simply initialize your custom class and present that as the view controller.

Comment: so, this must be basically what `performSegueWithIdentifer` does underneath right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When you perform a segue, the controller that you made the destination of the segue is instantiated from the storyboard.